# How do I HTML Display image dimensions (height and width) on image mouseover before upload?

Tags: javascript, html, image, size, ld-preload

How do I HTML Display image dimensions (height and width) on image mouseover before upload? Similar to that of Google Image Search...

https://www.google.com/search?num=100&newwindow=1&safe=off&sa=G&q=globe+logo&tbm=isch&tbs=simg:CAQSZxplCxCo1NgEGgQIAQgJDAsQsIynCBo8CjoIAhIU3wypFtwMqwyNCYYL8QqFC8cV2wwaIO0I0Ev39Yu595x37nhSmQ-pq8k3MhFJtbLxjeGNmyiEDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIE8SyJgAw,isz:l&ei=XOn0U7q2IIfdoAS-1IEY&ved=0CB8Q2A4oBA&biw=1282&bih=664

... I found...

http://aspforums.net/Threads/455444/Display-image-dimensions-height-and-width-on-image-mouseover-in-ASPNet/

... but there are a few issues with the code provided in that thread whereas the dimensions are not from the actual image source and the mouseover text appears below the image rather than cover over at the bottom.

Aside from the minor text displacement... how do I prefetch the size data just like in Google Images? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173796/html5-get-image-dimension should get you in track.

Comment: Thank You, Ervald. Now where do I click to up-vote your answer?

Comment: Hover your mouse over my comment and you'll see a 'up' arrow. Then you can close this question.

Comment: It's not giving me that option. If I hover the mouse over mine an 'x' at the bottom left would appear.

Comment: If you hover your mouse over my first comment you will see to the left of the comment an arrow pointing up and a flag under it.

Comment: I probably don't have the priviledge to vote yet strangely enough