# How do i check for low resolution photos when using cordova camera plugin?

Tags: cordova, camera, cordova-plugins

I have the following code. It pretty much works for hte most part. I'd like to catch people with crappy cameras and some how warn them their pictures will stink.   (using "cordova-plugin-camera" version 2.3.0)

```
           var cameraOpts = {
                quality: 100,
                // destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: $scope.sourceType,
                allowEdit: false,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                // popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                targetWidth: 186,
                targetHeight: 1024,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
                correctOrientation: true
            };

            $cordovaCamera.getPicture(cameraOpts).then(function(imageData) {
                var image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                $scope.setUpImage(index,image);

            }, function(err) {
                // error
                $scope.showAlert('Warning!', 'Camera cancelled!');
            });
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. I'm looking for a way to catch low resolution photos, and message the user.

Answer (score 0):

cordova camera plugin provide **quality** camera option but it does not provide any information about resolution(default is 100) ([enter link description here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#CameraOptions-quirks))

Comment: My quality is set to 100, and sometimes pictures are still blurry. I assume it depends on the users phone camera.

Comment: 100 is the default value in android even if you pass 50,android do not allow to down sample the image.

Comment: how about after image is acquired.. is there a way to check if image is blurry?

Comment: According to android docs native camera can capture a blurry image if **MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT** is not present. **MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT** is used to specify the destination location for the captured image to save.In cordova this is fully specified to cache location.link. So there is no way to get a blurry image of captured image.

Comment: How about after image is saved?  Is there a way in JS to detect a blurry image? (relatively?)   Like "There is a high possibility your images from this device are blurry. We advise you try a different device."?

Comment: different device test shows that no way that a camera capture blurry image in first place.There is no way in js which can alert/check quality of image capture from native.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an Image object (this is standard HTML5 API)

Relevant snippet copied from this answer:

[HTML5 - how to get image dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173796/html5-how-to-get-image-dimension)

From plugin doc: "The image is passed to the success callback as a Base64-encoded String, or as the URI for the image file"

If you choose base64 format in the camera plugin, the data URI would be

```
'data:image/jpg;base64,' + imageData
```

However, the plugin doc recommends the file format, which will return a file URL that you can assign directly to  your `image.src`

```
var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function(evt) {
            var width = this.width;
            var height = this.height;
            alert (width); // will produce something like 198
        };

        //here is where you pass the camera data to create the image
image.src = imageData;
```

As you can see, the method is asynchronous, you can wrap it in a `Promise` or emit an event when the image has been loaded and you have the width x height